# How to change the last (8th) bit of a byte to zero in java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, boolean-operations

**I have a byte for example:**

`"10000110"` which is `97` in decimal.

I don't know the correct ordering, some places it is written `"01100001"`, the point is that I'm speaking about the decimal number 97 which is stored in a single byte in our app.

We don't need bigger numbers than 100 in our app in this place of data and **we would like to store an additional boolean data in the last (8th) bit** in the corresponding byte, so..

1. I would like to write a 0 in the 8th bit **after** I've read that bit for the boolean information.

So this way I will have my boolean data from the 8th bit, and after that I can write the 8th bit to zero, so I can read my byte to get the decimal number. (because we only use values from 0-100 the last bit should always be zero.)

I don't know if it is clear enough, please let me know if you have any questions.

---

### So in short, my question is:

How could I write a 0 to the last bit of a byte in Java?

Comment: `"01100001" would be 97. Now you could only make the lsb zero as the hsb is already zero.

Comment: value &= 0xFE . And the value would become 96.

Comment: @blackapps It doesn't matter it is already zero, sometimes it will be one, as I described, it would be used to store a boolean value.

Comment: I dont understand your reaction. I told you how to make that bit zero and you dont even react on the given solution.

Comment: @blackapps You wrote "And the value would become 96", but it is 97, why did you subtract one?

Comment: Err, what about that "prior research" thing?! Didn't it occur to you to do a quick search on "java binary operations" or "java setting bits"?

Comment: When you write "the last bit", this is confusing. For most people this would mean the low-order bit (binary 00000001 or hex 01). You are really referring to the high-order bit (binary 10000000 or hex 80 or decimal 128).

Comment: I removed the `android` tag as this code has absolutely nothing to do with Android. It is a generic Java question (although the question is Java-specific, the question and the answers apply to other programming languages as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

97 decimal is 61 (hexadecimal) or 1100001 (binary)

If you want to use the high-order bit (10000000 binary or 80 hex) to store other information, you can do this as follows:

```
byte b = 97;
// Set the high-order bit to 1
byte c = b | 0x80;

// Determine if the high-order bit is set or not
boolean bitIsSet = (c & 0x80) != 0;

// clear the high-order bit (remove the high-order bit to get the value)
byte d = c & 0x7F;
```

I hope this is clear and answers your question.

Comment: note: `0x80 == 0b1000_0000` and `0x7F == 0b0111_1111`